Analysis of conflict between directional Radio an Wind turbines in QGIS 3.34
I have a directional radio track from point A (x,y,z) to point b (x,y,z). The directional radio shall be 3D-buffered (restriction area) to create an oval around the directional radio, similar to a tube. Typically point A and B are radio towers that are several to several tens of kilometers apart. Between point A and point B, I want to place windmills of a certain height. The windmills have a spherical rotor area.
In addition, I have a Digital Elevation Model with a resolution of up to 1 m.
Is there a way in QGIS to vizualize the windmills' 3D rotor area and the restriction area (fresnel zone) of the directional radio track in the 3D-Map-View?

Those are two questions. The first one can be approximated by simple geometric calculations, leaving out the earth's curvature. You know the ground height at all three locations, you know the antenna heights and the hub height, as well as rotor radius. Using these you can calculate whether the direct line between the antenna conflicts with the rotor, as well as the fresnel zone. Visualization is a different thing.

I need calculations as accurate as possible, so I should account for the earth curvature, shouldn't I? The ground height below the rotor sphere and the fresnel zone in the potential area of conflict is not constant as we are often planning in mountainous regions.

The hub has a fixed height above ground, hence a fixed area/space it covers, hence the radio track either collides with it, or not, no matter the ground level at the edge of the rotor.
